# How to rewrite URL as subdomain in asp.net without actually creating a subdomain on server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, subdomain

I hope this isn't the first time i'm asking this question on SO.

I've URLs in my website and which are using `query string` values
For example: **http://foo.com/xyzPage.aspx?barvalue=yehaa**

to

**http://yehaa.foo.com/**

Please suggest how it can be accomplished ***without actually creating subdomains on server*** ..

I've ***IIS 7.5*** installed on server machine and using ***Asp.net 4.0***.

Many thanks

Comment: You can do it using the Rewrite module for IIS.

Comment: any example please..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT** following our comments:

To access `http://foo.com/xyzPage.aspx?barvalue=yehaa` using `http://yehaa.foo.com/`, you have to use the following rule:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite subdomains">
        <match url="^/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+)\.foo\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://foo.com?barvalue={C:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

It matches every url ending or not with a `/` and using something before `foo.com` and then rewrites it to `http://foo.com?barvalue={C:1}` where `{C:1}` is whatever value was entered before `foo.com`.

If you want to prevent people from accessing directly to `http://foo.com?barvalue={C:1}`, you can use the rule below.

---

You could use the [Rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) by adding the following rule in your `web.config` file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to Subdomains" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^xyzPage.aspx$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^barvalue=(.+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}.{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It checks if the url matches exactly `xyzPage.aspx` (nothing before or after).
It checks if the querystring contains the `barvalue` parameter (and only this one) and if its value is not empty.
If those 2 conditions are ok, it triggers the `Redirect` to `http://barvalue.original.host`.

Your question specify `Rewrite`, so if this is really what you want to do, change the action `type="Redirect"` to `type="Rewrite"`.

**Important**: you may need the [Application Request Routing module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) installed and setup with the proxy mode enabled to `Rewrite` to a different domain.

Comment: @MayankPathak When you say "without actually creating subdomains on server", what do you want the user to see then? How should the server know what content to render?

Comment: @nicolas.. What i want is, there will be a page and product will vary on page by `query string`. And based on query string i want to make subdomains...i just want to rewrite URL as subdomain..

Comment: @MayankPathak What is still unclear to me is: Your real URL (the one that works) is `http://foo.com/xyzPage.aspx?barvalue=yehaa` and you want your users to see it as `http://yehaa.foo.com/` in their browser? Or is it the other way? Or did I miss something?

Comment: I just installed `ARR` and configured it..but it shows `HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found` error after setting up `ARR`. But before installing it was working as redirect to `subdomain.` Please help

Comment: @MayankPathak have you enabled the proxy mode?

Comment: Can you try to use the [failed request tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see where does the 404 come from? It is a 5min setup and can help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting tracing tool..it really helped me a lot..at least now i'm able to see where i'm lacking..Sorry Mate, i'm marking again your [ost answer :) will post another question with that specific error....rule works fine, rewrites the url but something again rewrites URL to original URL...that error will post as new question..

Comment: I am into similiar situation. that is 404. But I am suspecting its because my server is shared by two domains. Can anybody list the bindings that i need to have on my website ? I suspect i am missing some binding as well.