# Can we create subdomain URLs without actually creating a subdomain in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, subdomain, urlrewriter.net

Is this possible to mimic URLs in Asp.net without actually creating a sub domain.
Is this possible using [URLRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/). I've to use URLRewriter only. I'm using asp.net 4.0 and IIS 6. So i won't user IIS 7's URL rewriting extensions..

For example : URL : **example.com?value=somecode**

and rewrite as : **somecode.example.com**

I just gone through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/85912/Sub-Domain-Implementation-using-Urlrewriter-NET-AS) link on code project. I just don't know how to implement in project.

Any help is appreciated..!!!

**EDIT :**

As per [Juann Strauss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333809/can-we-create-subdomain-urls-without-actually-creating-a-subdomain-in-asp-net/15334044?noredirect=1#15334044). I'm updating my question now.
Is it possible using **IIS 7**. without actually creating a subdomain.?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Your server won't be listening for requests to **somecode.example.com**. If you want to do something like that, you're going to have to do scripting on the IIS level rather than on a site level. There's also DHCP configuration to think of.

what you CAN do is route requests for **example.com?value=somecode** to **example.com/somecode**

Comment: If on server level..than how..?

Comment: Honestly, I am not quite sure. It's probably a new question you should pose. But you can try working through this article first: http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_asp_net/3194877.htm

Comment: The reason I said to ask a new question is because your's has fallen off the front page by now, so I don't think anyone will see it for a long time.

Comment: Okay..here's my new question with a bounty offered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248094/how-to-rewrite-querystring-url-as-subdomain-in-asp-net