# How can I map A directory of Main Application as another domain?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to set `www.domain.com/folder` as `folder.domain.com`. Both must run as same application.

Comment: This is not really clear. You want to access the content from `www.domain.com/folder` using the url `folder.domain.com`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly ya exactly... I don't want to create a domain for this...

Comment: Could this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15275533/1443490 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following rule in your web.config file -

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>    
         <rule name="FolderSubDomain" stopProcessing="false">
           <match url="(.*)" />
             <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.domain\.com$" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: pointing to folder consider it as another application. I can't access the session state or cache from Main Application

Comment: I already created a subdomain folder.domain.com . Now IIS maps it into that folder.

Comment: @SubinJacob - try the alternate way then. I have removed new solution option.

Comment: what this means `{C:1}/{R:1}` ?

Comment: Should I remove the site folder.domain.com that I created already before setting the web.config to the main app

Comment: if your url is folder.domain.com, `{R:1}` matches `folder` and  `{C:1}` matches `domain.com`. So url `"{C:1}/{R:1}"` results in `domain.com/folder`

Comment: @SubinJacob - yes, remove that newly created site

Comment: Read more about url rewriting. You will get an idea what exactly you need to do. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: That means all subfolders can be accessed via subdomains. rite? Thanks for the guide

Comment: `The requested resource is not found.` this error shown while I added it to web.config

Comment: No. I installed rewrite module. (no config changes made). but still 404 error showing. However, I can access domain.com/folder. (testing on local network with domain configured locally)