# URL rewrite rule as Subdomain not working

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module, arr

i'm using below rule to rewrite URL as subdomain.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to Subdomains" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^LandingPage.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^val=(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}.{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it's not working. it's taking me to the Main domain.
I've added wild card DNS in my SOA hosting file. and have installed ARR on IIS with proxy mode enabled.

I'll be entering URL as `http://www.example.com/LandingPage.aspx?val=somevalue`

And this rule rewrite it as `somevalue.example.com/`. Still it's not working. Please correct me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Yes...my another question was answered perfectly...see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248094/how-to-rewrite-url-as-subdomain-in-asp-net-without-actually-creating-a-subdomain